How the expectation definition in measure theory implies the definitions in elementary school probability.
I study measure theory and probability and we define the expectation of a R.V , X ( i.e , a measurable function) how:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]= \int_{\Omega}X\hspace{.2 cm} d\mathbb{P} $$
Then by the change variable theorem follow that:
$$\int_{\Omega'}u \hspace{.2 cm} dT(\mu)=\int_{\Omega}u\circ T \hspace{.2 cm}d\mu $$
With $T:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega'\hspace{.2 cm}$ Measurable ,
$\mu\hspace{.2 cm}$ measure in $\Omega$, and $$T(\mu)=\mu\circ T^{-1}$$ the push forward of $\mu$ under $T$.
Particulary take $u=I_d$ the identity function in $\mathbb{R}\hspace{.2 cm}$,$T=X$ the R.V, and $\mu=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$.
Then by the change variable theorem follow that :
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]= \int_{\mathbb{R}}x\hspace{.2 cm}d(\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1})(x)=:\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\hspace{.2 cm}d\mu(x)\color{red}{=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x)\hspace{.2 cm}dx} $$.
Mi doubt is how obtains the red equality? (for absolute continuous function)
I think that $d\mu(x)$ turns this $f(x)$ by using the Random Nikodin theorem , but I'dont find this calculations in any book.
And how prove the discrete formula for a discrete R.V ( this follow by the change variable theorem but is the first time that i see this things and i'm confused in this calculations !!)

Well, it's kind of a tautology: $\int_{\Bbb R}x d\mu=\int_{\Bbb R} x f(x),dx$ is true when $\mu$ is a measure such that there is some $f$ such that for all Borel sets $A$, $\mu(A)=\int_{\Bbb R}1_A(x)f(x),dx$. And in fact sometimes such an $f$ does not exist.
